# Setting a variable to linq query with no results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a table that holds links to websites about particular theaters.  I want to retrieve the first link for a given theater.  My code to set the variable:

```
Dim link As String = TheaterLinks.Where(Function(x) x.TheaterID = TheaterID).FirstOrDefault().Link
```

If there are no results (some theaters won't have any links), then I get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do I do this?  I tried:

```
Dim link As String = Links.Where(Function(x) x.TheaterID = TheaterID.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Link
```

But I can't figure out what to put inside DefaultIfEmpty().  I tried DefaultIfEmpty("") and DefaultIfEmpty(blankstringvariable) but then I get:

```
Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to type 'TheaterLink'.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `FirstOrDefault()` is allowed to return `null`, in which case accessing `Link` property would throw an exception.

If you use [VB.NET 14](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2431727), add question mark for automatic null checking:

```
Dim link As String = TheaterLinks.Where(Function(x) x.TheaterID = TheaterID).FirstOrDefault()?.Link
```

(see `?.Link` instead of `.Link`)

Otherwise, do it in two stages: first, get the object using `FirstOrDefault`, then null-check it manually with an `If` statement.

Comment: How can I do it in two stages if I can't set the results of the query to any kind of variable?  There's nothing I could use in an If statement.  Using FirstOrDefault()? fixed one of my problems.  Now I moved on to a date field and FirstOrDefault()? gives me a "Nullable object must have a value" error.  (You would think something nullable could be null.)

Comment: @GrantSmith Since omitting the type implicitly types the variable, you can write `Dim obj = TheaterLinks.Where(Function(x) x.TheaterID = TheaterID).FirstOrDefault()`, and check `obj` for `Nothing` before accessing its fields.

Answer (score 0):

For my original example, I just had to add a question mark:

```
Dim link As String = Links.Where(Function(x) x.ID = id).FirstOrDefault()?.Link
```

I tried doing this in my model and got a "Nullable object must have a value" error, so I did the two-stage approach:

```
Dim eventDate = Events.Where(Function(x) x.ID = id).FirstOrDefault()?.EventDate
If eventDate.HasValue Then
     'some code
Else
     'some code
End If
```